# How to Refresh a DIV every X Seconds

Tags: jquery

I want to refresh a DIV element every X seconds which is in same page (not in external page). My site is video streaming site and I want to refresh advertisement in background when viewer watchs the video. There is template of my advertisement codes :

```
<div id="advert123">
<script type="text/javascript">
Advertisement codes
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge about js or jquery. So I searched for an answer but all solutions I found that were about loading and refreshing a DIV from external php file.

Comment: I have edited my question. Advertisement is dynamic.

Comment: No not randomly. I just want to refresh script code in <div id="advert123"></div> every 5 minute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your advert isn't random, and it's just refreshing the div contents (maybe due to the content being a video), then you can use jQuery in this way:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    function refresh()
    {
        var div = $('#target-div'),
            divHtml = div.html();

        div.html(divHtml);
    }

    setInterval(function()
    {
        refresh()
    }, 300000); //300000 is 5minutes in ms
})
```

this will refresh div contents every 5 minutes.

refs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

https://api.jquery.com/Html/

Comment: Maybe also change `target-div` to his desired `advert123`, otherwise he will post `excuse me sir, I copied your code but it doesn't work at all, please help me`

Comment: Thanks you. It worked! :)

Comment: @Yearmaz np :p :)